# Determining types of memory used by Spring Boot application causing an OOM kill

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, docker-container

I have a container running on Kubernetes with a Spring Boot application.
The code configures a few REST controllers and saves some data to an H2 file through JPA.
I'd say the main dependencies here are:

- `spring-boot-starter-jersey:2.6.6`
- `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.6`

When monitoring memory utilization,
I can see that it is increasing very slowly and eventually causes an OOM kill.
More specifically, the kernel is killing the process,
the JVM is not killing itself,
so no dump file is created
(and the heap doesn't seem to be the problem, see below).

Some relevant configuration of the container/JVM:

- Container's requests and limits for memory: 400Mi
- JDK 17.0.2
- `-Xms134217728`
- `-Xmx134217728`
- `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=16m`
- `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m`
- `-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=10`

I extracted some Prometheus metrics when the container first started:

```
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="Tenured Gen",} 8.9522176E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods'",} 1.7891328E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="Eden Space",} 3.5782656E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 1.08003328E8
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",} 2555904.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="Survivor Space",} 4456448.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 1.4614528E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods'",} 4784128.0
```

And also after the container had been running for about a week:

```
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="Tenured Gen",} 8.9522176E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods'",} 3.3554432E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="Eden Space",} 3.5782656E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 1.15933184E8
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",} 2555904.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="heap",id="Survivor Space",} 4456448.0
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 1.4680064E7
jvm_memory_committed_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods'",} 2.2544384E7

jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="mapped - 'non-volatile memory'",} 0.0
jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="mapped",} 0.0
jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="direct",} 185594.0

jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="Tenured Gen",} 7.2898432E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods'",} 2.7538688E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="Eden Space",} 1.7707368E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Metaspace",} 1.153388E8
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-nmethods'",} 1498880.0
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="heap",id="Survivor Space",} 205584.0
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="Compressed Class Space",} 1.442888E7
jvm_memory_used_bytes{area="nonheap",id="CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods'",} 2.2109184E7
```

From these, it seems to me that there's no leak in the memory managed by the JVM.
I also checked `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat` inside the container when it was near the limit:

```
cache 3649536
rss 411545600
rss_huge 0
mapped_file 249856
swap 0
pgpgin 67578153
pgpgout 67476787
pgfault 242802886
pgmajfault 15
inactive_anon 32768
active_anon 411631616
inactive_file 2465792
active_file 1044480
unevictable 0
hierarchical_memory_limit 419430400
hierarchical_memsw_limit 9223372036854771712
total_cache 3649536
total_rss 411545600
total_rss_huge 0
total_mapped_file 249856
total_swap 0
total_pgpgin 0
total_pgpgout 0
total_pgfault 0
total_pgmajfault 0
total_inactive_anon 32768
total_active_anon 411631616
total_inactive_file 2465792
total_active_file 1044480
total_unevictable 0
```

I can only guess that something is using native memory in the JVM
(no other process is running inside the container),
but is there any way I can determine if this is the case?
I know about [`ByteBuffer`](https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshooting-problems-with-native-off-heap-memo) but

a) `XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` would limit that, right?

b) metric `jvm_buffer_memory_used_bytes{id="direct",}` is in the order of KB.

So I'm wondering if there is something in Spring (Boot) that I'm missing,
or if there's some other JVM tuning parameter that I must set to limit memory effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there will be heap dump file(.hprof) that is created when OOM occurs.
You can use any heap dump analyser to look for the objects consuming high memory.

This [link](https://dzone.com/articles/java-heap-dump-analyzer-1) might help you

Comment: Unfortunately there's none, the dump file is created if the JVM itself detects that it ran out of memory, but that's not the case here, the OOM status is detected by the kernel, so the JVM is killed without warning. Also, from the Prometheus metrics, it seems to me that the JVM believes there's still a lot of memory available.